# Как настроить разработку на git для верстальщиков.

Tags: php, git

Мы команда из 4 человек разработчиков, проблема в следующем что когда работали только фроненды проблем не было у каждого на локалке был проект и все работали через гит. Но возникла проблема постоянно верстальщику в видах нужно править код на сервере но туда лазят и бекенды и попросту затираем друг другу файлы. Как можно решить проблему, слышал гит можно развернуть на самом сервере и работать с ветками.

Comment: Как деплой бэкенда устроен у вас? Почему верстальщик правит код бэкенда напрямую на сервере, а не в репозитории?

Comment: в репозитарии вы имеете введу у себя на локалке?

Comment: @ukroficer да, наверняка он имел в виду это. Нормальный путь - править локально, коммитить в репозиторий и разворачивать на бой (или на тестовый сервер). Подробнее есть тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/580881/181472