# Автоматический ежедневный коммит в репозиторий git

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git

Как реализовать автоматический коммит и пуш в удаленный репозиторий используя базовые утилиты Ubuntu? Как корректно обработать отсутствие изменений?
Данный репозиторий планируется использовать для архивного хранения изменений на сайте без cms.

У нас уже нормально используется git для хранения кода, но вот сейчас задумались о том, чтобы хранить сайт без cms в git. Это даже скорее архивное хранение. Ну и "отчетность" о том, что и когда меняли

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47166/discussion-on-question-by-alexey-shabalin-----).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По моему личному мнению, всё нужно делать ровно наоборот.

Вы меняете сайт напрямую и хотите сохранять изменения постфактум.

- В результате у вас будет только информация о том, в какой день изменилась та или иная строка, но никакой информации о точном времени и авторе изменения. А когда нет информации об авторе, нет и ответственности.
- А ещё изменения, внесённые в течение дня, не будут иметь бэкапа.
- Изменения также не будут иметь осмысленного комментария. Зачем что-то поменяли или добавили? Через неделю уже никто не вспомнит.

Считайте, что вы купите абонемент на факапы. Другими словами, технически ваша задача решается очень легко (cron + git), но эта задача не приблизит вас к цели - бэкапам и отчетности об изменениях.

Гораздо более надёжный способ - проводить все изменения сразу и исключительно через git, разворачивая боевое окружение из определённой ветки (обычно `master` или `production`). Способов разворачивать сайт из git множество и они за рамками этого вопроса.

Суть вот в чём: если кто-то захотел поменять хоть даже одну строку - делает коммит в ветку, из которой разворачивается сайт. Если этот коммит всё сломал - откатываемся на прошлый и делаем выводы.

Очень хорошо и надёжно будет использовать тестовое окружение, чтобы не выкатывать сразу на бой. В таком случае вы либо разворачиваете сайт на тестовое окружение из каждой feature-ветки, или из какой-то одной, в которую мержатся feature-ветки. Довольно распространённая практика: `master` разворачивается на stage, `production` разворачивается на бой.

Про развертывание сайтов из git:

- Не самые современные методы: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git)
- Вполне современный метод: [(Habr) GitLab CI: Учимся деплоить](https://habrahabr.ru/company/softmart/blog/310502/)
- [Using Git to manage a web site](http://toroid.org/git-website-howto)
- [How To Set Up Automatic Deployment with Git with a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps)

Про модель работы и релизы (каждое изменение на бою - это релиз, хоть и небольшой)

- [Как правильно отправить релиз на git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573743/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b0-git)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ с ссылками, пойду с ним к колегам

Comment: @AlexeyShabalin буду рад, если он вам поможет. Если возникнут ещё вопросы по этой теме, оповестите меня комментарием обязательно, наверняка что-нибудь подскажу )

Answer (score 0):

Используйте утилиту `Cron` + `Bash`. 
В `Cron` задаете период, который будет соответствовать вызову `Bash` файла. В нем необходимо будет прописать скрипит перехода в директорию репозитория и добавить вот такие команды:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "время коммита, например"
git push [server] [branch]
```

Далее просто запускаете `Cron`-скрипт и все.

Но да, это извращение, если Вы начали использовать `Git` - то будьте добры, разберитесь в нем и для чего он нужен, иначе толку от него будет не очень много.

Comment: я думаю, что Вы прекрасно понимаете, что это будет работать для одного разработчика. Для двух уже нет.

Comment: А как же коммит?

Comment: Он же не ребенок, наверняка знает, что в начале делать коммит, а потом только пушить.
Но я с вами согласен, делать такое через автоматику - это какое-то извращение.

Comment: @Aquinary Ваши слова "и добавить вот такую команду:" как бы намекают, что это пошаговое руководство.

Comment: Однако, ответ на поставленный вопрос тоже должен присутствовать, хоть сам вопрос и идеологически неверный

Answer (score 0):

GIT не подходит для этой задачи, так он создан для того что бы хранить и отслеживать только изменения в проекте опираясь на действия разработчиков. Хранение проектов с их описаниями и фиксации времени задача для программ из другой категории.